# Helm template returning same value in all cases

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I am trying to set terminationgraceperiodseconds in my deployment.yaml.
I am performing two steps

1. checking if lifecycle hook is enabled and shutdowndelay is present in values.yaml
   then add value of delay in sleep to terminationgraceperiod

   ```
   {{-  $delay := hasKey .Values "shutdownDelay" | ternary .Values.shutdownDelay 30 }}
   {{-  $graceperiod := hasKey .Values.service "terminationGracePeriodSeconds" | ternary .Values.service.terminationGracePeriodSeconds 120 }}
   {{- if or .Values.lifecycleHooks.enabled (gt ( int $delay ) 0 )}}
   terminationGracePeriodSeconds: {{ add $graceperiod $delay }}
   {{- else }}
   terminationGracePeriodSeconds: {{ int $graceperiod }}
   {{- end }}
   ```

but everytime i am running the code it gives me 150 no matter what the value of lifecycle enable is

values.yaml

```
#shutdownDelay: 40
lifecycleHooks:
  enabled: true

service:
terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 120
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: 90; not 120 or 150?  Do you have a specific set of Helm values (either `helm install --set` options or a YAML file) that you think should produce different behavior?

Comment: sorry 150 always

Comment: it is always giving me stale values and I am not able to figure out why

Comment: added the sample values.yaml

Comment: I am using helm template command

Comment: do you have any idea what I am doing wrong here

Comment: You `add $graceperiod $delay` whenever the hooks are enabled _or_ the delay is positive; do you mean this to be an `and` check?

Comment: hope you won't delete this question after getting an answer, noticed it quite a few times.

Comment: @DavidMaze: I want add it not and. I want to check if hook is enabled and if it is enabled then it should add the delay value to graceperiod. Do you see any issue with the code?

Comment: Ah let me try that with `and`

Comment: @DavidMaze: I took reference from here : https://github.com/gruntwork-io/helm-kubernetes-services/blob/master/charts/k8s-service/templates/_deployment_spec.tpl#L230 so it means that it isn't correct?

Comment: @DavidMaze: Yes it works with tha `and` condition so does that mean I need an `and` in lifecycle also? or the or there would work?

Comment: But I think now I will have to change the logic of. lifecycle hook, it should work with an `or` only

Comment: since value of shutdowndelay conflicts with prestop hook, I will have to change the old code. Might post a new question too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You add the value if `lifecycleHooks.enabled` is true *or* if `$delay` is positive

```
{{- if or .Values.lifecycleHooks.enabled (gt ( int $delay ) 0 )}}
{{/*   ^^                                                    */}}
```

It sounds like you do not want to do the addition if the `enabled` flag is false; you only want to do it if the flag is true *and* `$delay` is positive

```
{{- if and .Values.lifecycleHooks.enabled (gt ( int $delay ) 0 )}}
{{/*   ^^^                                                   */}}
```

If you believe the delay will never be negative, then you can simplify this by removing the `gt 0` case; adding zero to something leaves it unchanged.

```yaml
{{- if .Values.lifecycleHooks.enabled }}
terminationGracePeriodSeconds: {{ add $graceperiod $delay }}
{{- else }}
terminationGracePeriodSeconds: {{ int $graceperiod }}
{{- end }}
```

This is also another place you can do tricks with `ternary`, again taking advantage of adding zero being a no-op.  You could set another variable to be a copy of `$delay` if the `enabled` flag is true, or zero if not, and then it's safe to just `add` it without another conditional.

```yaml
{{- $extraDelay := .Values.lifecycleHooks.enabled | ternary $delay 0 }}
terminationGracePeriodSeconds: {{ add $graceperiod $extraDelay }}
```

Comment: Thanks it made the code much cleaner. But I got into another problem.

Comment: Loved your optimisations

Comment: How can I append one more condition like don't add extradelay if `.Values.lifecycleHooks.preStop` is there ?

Comment: Or I should post a new question?

Comment: Can you help me with my new questions, it has become really complex to make changes https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73366514/how-to-add-extra-condition-in-helm-chart-to-make-it-work-for-all-use-cases

Comment: Can we check here that .Values.lifecycleHooks.preStop is present and .Values.lifecycleHooks.enabled then  $delay 0

Comment: So you _can_ do just about anything in Helm templates; but if you start writing complex logic you start running into lack of good unit-test support, unusual syntax, and little knowledge across your development team.  If you have this much logic a totally different path you can consider is writing an _operator_ in another general-purpose language, usually Go.  That doesn't participate in the Helm ecosystem but there's also much less weird syntax and you can use a normal build-test-deploy lifecycle.

Comment: is there a way i can implement this one Can we check here that .Values.lifecycleHooks.preStop is present and .Values.lifecycleHooks.enabled then $delay 0